# Fixed positioning/z-index issue in ios

Tags: html, ios, css, scroll, z-index

So I have run into the fixed positioning issue on mobile safari, the scenario is as follows

I have a header which has position relative and then in my main content I have a modal type thing which is suppose to overlay all the screen including the header. That modal thing has position fixed. The issue is the modal doesn't overlay the header and gets behind the header.

I have tried using z-index on both didn't worked, I tried the transform property fix didn't worked.

Can I get some help?

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
<div class="inner-wrap">

    // this the headr
    <nav class="tab-bar show-for-medium-down">
        <section class="right-small">
            <a class="right-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon">
                <span></span>
            </a>
        </section>

        <section class="section-header">
            <span data-bind="text: selectedLocation().friendlyName" class="location-name"></span>
        </section>

        <section class="nav-back">
            <button class="tiny back" data-bind="click: $root.navBack"><i class="fi-arrow-left"></i></button>
        </section>

    </nav>

    // .. other menu items

    <aside class="main-section">
        <div id="appview" class="loading">
            <div id="workspace" class="map_canvas">

                <section id="map-stuff" data-bind="visible:mapView">
                    // some stuff goes here  
                </section>

                <section class="other-stuff">
                    // in here I have the layoue item
                </section>

            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide some of your code so we can see how you're structuring your site.

Comment: provide some of your code.

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell from the code you've provided but it sounds like this might be a problem with your [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). You could try setting a z-index for each major section of your page.